# How do we write spin multiplicity for Mn(2+), Mn(7+)?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, electronic-configuration, atomic-structure, spin

Mn has atomic number = 25

Since it is an exception to electronic configuration , unlike having = $\mathrm{3d^7}$ , it has electronic configuration = $\mathrm{3d^5,4s^2}$.

Formula for spin multiplicity = 2|S| + 1.

Spin multiplicity of Mn = 2(0) + 1 = 1 since there are no unpaired electrons.

I’m having difficulty with the further ions multiplicity.

For $\ce{Mn2+}$ , there are 5 unpaired electrons in d sub-shell. The 2e- of $\mathrm{4s^2}$ are lost.

M = 2(5/2) + 1 = 6. Now , according to my textbook. Mn = Mn2+ in terms multiplicity which I do not see as correct.

M for $\ce{Mn7+}$ ,

Electron configuration =$\mathrm{2s^2}$, $\mathrm{3d^0}$

Therefore , here I think it should be 2(2/2) + 1 = 3.

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting ( not to be applied to titles ):
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [chem/math formula/equation formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Generally, only math variables and scientific quantities are in italic, most other things,like chemical formulas and orbital symbols are upright.

Comment: @Poutnik I will edit my Q in some time accordingly as it can be useful.

Comment: Sure, no hurry because of me, just for you to be aware for future cases.

Answer (score 4):

*Spin multiplicity* = $2S+1$, where $S$ is the total spin angular momentum. Now $S = \frac{n}{2}$ where $n$ represents total number of unpaired electrons. So now we can write **spin multiplicity** = $n+1$.

Now coming to your question,

- $\ce{Mn}$ has 5 unpaired electrons in it. Therefore, its spin multiplicity $(S) = 5+1 = 6$.
- Similarly, $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$ has 5 unpaired elections in it. Therefore, its spin multiplicity $(S) = 5+1=6$.
- $\ce{Mn^{7+}}$ has zero number of unpaired electrons. Therefore, its spin multiplicity $(S) = 0+1=1$.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the formatting guide posted as a comment to the original question.

Comment: Consider also [the usage of *it's* versus *its*](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/its-vs-its/).